# Executing individual opcodes from debugger

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, bytecode, pdb, cpython

I've written a `sys.settrace` function:

```
import sys
def tracefunc(frame, event, arg):
    if event == 'call':
        if '__debug_me__' in frame.f_code.co_names:
            return tracefunc
        return None
    if frame is not None:
        print(event, frame.f_code, frame.f_lasti)
        # I am stuck here
```

Whenever a `STORE_NAME` is encountered, I want to do something like:

```
print(frame.f_code.co_names[namei], old_val, new_val)
```

but I can't think of any way of doing this that would be proof against:

```
x=1;y=2;z=3
```

or the like; Python's `sys.settrace` stops on each line, but that's about it. I could solve this problem by executing individual opcodes and reading the frame's stack... but how can I do *that*?

Is there any way to step through individual opcodes (as opposed to lines) in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Python 3.7 you can set `f_trace_opcodes` on the frame object that you get from the tracing function. You can then catch the `opcode` event to effectively step by opcode. For older versions of Python you could use the trick of re-aligning each opcode on a new line (see https://github.com/P403n1x87/podb/commit/975350ccb1496e3093380797f9fefbf1d102ae2e). An example of an experimental poor-man's opcode-based debugger is at https://github.com/P403n1x87/podb